# how to see list of tables and list of trigger(and sequences)?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence

In my database there are lots of sequences, triggers and tables. I'm confused each time which  table is associated to which trigger(and sequence). How to see these list in single query?

Comment: @Alex Poole  i saw that but it showing zero rows selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle, you cannot find which sequence is used on which table, it is not associated on table level. For that you need to find the code, and search for the sequence where it is been used, may be it is used on before insert trigger or in the PL/SQL code.

For trigger, you can see the data dictionary views

```
select table_name,
       trigger_name as object_name,
       'TRIGGER' object_type 
from ALL_TRIGGERS
```

**EDIT**
My way of finding a sequence is

1. Suppose i want to check where 'Seq_ID' is been used .
2. Select * from dba_source where lower(text) like '%seq_id.nextval%';
3. This will tell me the code where the sequence is been referenced ,probably you can find insert statement in the code ,from that you can find that this sequence is associated with which table
4. Or it will give you the trigger code ,and from the trigger you can find which table is referred.

Comment: @guruv then how to see which table is associated on which sequence?

Comment: @user2801653:please find the edit part

Answer (score 1):

In sql server, you can use sys.triggers and sys.tables like,

```
     select ta.name AS 'TableName', tg.name 'TriggerName' from sys.triggers tg 
     INNER JOIN sys.tables ta ON tg.parent_id = ta.object_id
```

Comment: The question is clearly about Oracle.

Comment: I think, solution works in sql server whether this is oracle question. Please vote to encourage me as new comer...

Comment: Sory, but why should I upvote an answer which does not work for the person asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

You get this details from dependency table.

```
select * from user_dependencies where (referenced_type like 'TRIGGER' OR 
 referenced_type = 'SEQUENCE') and type = 'TABLE';
```

Comment: your showing now row selected

Comment: There is no relation between a sequence and a table in Oracle and therefor there are no dependencies listed `user_dependencies`. And to get the triggers related to a table, the condition must be the other way round `type = 'TRIGGER' and referenced_type = 'TABLE'`. Btw: using `LIKE` without a wildcard does not make any sense.

Comment: Is the triggers and table in you schema. if not then use all_dependencies table with schema filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the trigger and sequences with the following statment

```
    select 
         table_name, trigger_name, referenced_name as sequence_name
    from 
        all_triggers 
   join all_dependencies 
   on name = trigger_name and  referenced_type = 'SEQUENCE'
    ;
```

Comment: gud but showing end of the columns Only 5,000 rows currently supported in a script results